# Org Mode use radio target for Chinese Texts

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Radio targets in `org-mode` work by recognizing spacing between words. This makes the function redundant in when work wth Chinese and Japanese texts.

I discovered an interesting function in `ol.el` with a comment that says:

> Some languages, e.g., Chinese, do not use spaces to separate words.  Also allow to surround radio targets with line-breakable characters.

```el
(defun org-update-radio-target-regexp ()
  "Find all radio targets in this file and update the regular expression.
Also refresh fontification if needed."
  (interactive)
  (let ((old-regexp org-target-link-regexp)
    ;; Some languages, e.g., Chinese, do not use spaces to
    ;; separate words.  Also allow to surround radio targets with
    ;; line-breakable characters.
    (before-re "\\(?:^\\|[^[:alnum:]]\\|\\c|\\)\\(")
    (after-re "\\)\\(?:$\\|[^[:alnum:]]\\|\\c|\\)")
    (targets
     (org-with-wide-buffer
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (let (rtn)
        (while (re-search-forward org-radio-target-regexp nil t)
          ;; Make sure point is really within the object.
          (backward-char)
          (let ((obj (org-element-context)))
        (when (eq (org-element-type obj) 'radio-target)
          (cl-pushnew (org-element-property :value obj) rtn
                  :test #'equal))))
        rtn))))
    (setq org-target-link-regexp
      (and targets
           (concat before-re
               (mapconcat
            (lambda (x)
              (replace-regexp-in-string
               " +" "\\s-+" (regexp-quote x) t t))
            targets
            "\\|")
               after-re)))
    (unless (equal old-regexp org-target-link-regexp)
      ;; Clean-up cache.
      (let ((regexp (cond ((not old-regexp) org-target-link-regexp)
              ((not org-target-link-regexp) old-regexp)
              (t
               (concat before-re
                   (mapconcat
                    (lambda (re)
                      (substring re (length before-re)
                         (- (length after-re))))
                    (list old-regexp org-target-link-regexp)
                    "\\|")
                   after-re)))))
    (when (featurep 'org-element)
      (org-with-point-at 1
        (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
          (org-element-cache-refresh (match-beginning 1))))))
      ;; Re fontify buffer.
      (when (memq 'radio org-highlight-links)
    (org-restart-font-lock)))))
```

Running the function on the sample text below shows that only 1 and 2 are linked.

```el
 <<<劉邵>>>


1. 劉邵

2. 其邯鄲淳事在〈王粲傳〉，蘇林事在〈劉邵〉、〈高堂隆傳〉，樂詳事在〈杜畿傳〉。

3. 六月，權令將軍賀齊督糜芳、劉邵等襲蘄春，邵等生虜宗。
```

How do we make radio targets work without the spacing requirement?

Comment: Does anyone know how `wikipedia` tags proper names, especially in languages with no spacing in between words such as Chinese? I am looking for a function very similar to that in `org-mode` and the radio target is what I've found. Would welcome any suggestions to do otherwise.

Comment: Hidden `xml` tagging that is indexed, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the UTF-8 character [Zero Width Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) to *invisible* separate your targets from the rest of the text.

You can insert that character by using `C-x 8 <ret>` `zero width space`.

This seems the easiest option, but with a tradeof. Because, when introducing a new radio target, you need to do a search-replace operation (to insert those invisible spaces into the text).

Comment: Interesting idea. But I'd like better to have a radio target function that supports Chinese text search, separate from the original radio target function.

Comment: Is there a mode that can show zero width spaces? `whitespace-mode` doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: @Sati it is possible with `whitespace-mode` together with [`unicode-whitespace`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/unicode-whitespace.el). This additional requires [`ucs-utils`](https://github.com/rolandwalker/ucs-utils) and [`list-utils`](https://github.com/rolandwalker/list-utils) and some adjustments. But `whitespace-mode` does not what you expect, read its documentation!